# Why this Perl program is not giving expected output?

Tags: perl

```
open ( F1, "file1.txt" );
open ( F2, "+>file2.txt" );
$/ = "\n\n" ;
while (<F1>) {
    print F2;
    $/ = "\n" ;
    @arr = <F2>  ;
    @found = grep(/^: /, @arr);
    if( $#found == -1) {
        truncate(F2, $length);
    }
    $/ = "\n\n" ;
}
```

Please help me to find the error in this code.

file1.txt:

```
:a
:b

: x
:y
```

**note:**:a , :b  and : x , :y are separated by "\n" and :b and :x by "\n\n"

Expected contents in file2.txt after execution of program:

```
: x
:y
```

Comment: You will have to do better than "not working" if you expect to get help.

Comment: Where does `$length` come from?

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you are expecting versus what you are seeing.

Comment: I used truncate(F2,$length);  to remove the entire contents of F2, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: is this code raising an error?

Comment: I suggest you put ``use strict`` at the top and notice that you a using ``$length`` without defining it.

Comment: What does this ``$#found == -1`` suppose to do? it looks like bad pasting

Comment: okay i am replacing it

Comment: i will use : if(grep(/^: /,<F2>)) .i got a working replacement for this code.i want to post that.help me to reopen this post.

Comment: @nrathaus It checks if the last index of the `@found` array is `-1` -- if the array is empty. You could also do `if (@found == 0)` or just `if (@found)`, or `if (grep /../)` like guru says last here.

Answer (score 5):

There are things wrong with your program, but its difficult to tell what you might be referring to, since you do not actually specify a problem or a question.

```
open ( F1, "file1.txt" );
open ( F2, "+>file2.txt" );
```

You should use three argument open, with explicit mode and lexical file handle. Also, you should check the return value of the `open` to see that it did not fail and why. Also, using better names for file handles does not hurt.

```
open my $in,  "<",  "file1.txt" or die "Cannot open file1.txt for reading: $!";
open my $out, "+>", "file2.txt" or die "Cannot open file2.txt for overwrite: $!";
```

Do note that the file open mode `+>` will truncate your file when you open it, but allow you to both read and write to/from the file handle. Most of the time, you do not want this.

```
$/ = "\n\n" ;
while (<F1>) {
```

Setting the input record separator to `$/` will read paragraphs from your input file, in your case (assuming I got the formatting right), that would be

```
$_ = ":a
:b
";
```

You then print this value to your output file

```
print F2;    # this means "print F2 $_"
```

You then change the input record separator again, and read all the lines in your output file:

```
$/ = "\n" ;
@arr = <F2>  ;
```

But unfortunately, this is wrong, because the position of the file handle will be at the end of file (`eof`), because this is a file handle your are printing to. So `@arr` will be empty.

```
@found = grep(/^: /, @arr);
if( $#found == -1) {
    truncate(F2, $length);
}
```

So this code, with the `truncate` will always happen. Also, of course, `$length` is an undefined variable, so it will give you a warning such as `Use of uninitialized value $length in truncate at ...` unless you have been so foolish as to not use:

```
use warnings;
```

I assume that what you are trying to do here is to check the input received before printing it to the output, but you should know that trying to print and truncate afterwards is a horrible idea. Why not check it before printing it instead? That's not only how its done 99.99% of the times, its also the simplest and most logical way to do it.

```
if (/^: /) {
    print $out $_;
}
```

`/^: /` is short for `$_ =~ /^: /`, in case you are uncertain -- it applies a regex match operator to the default input variable `$_`, which are what you are reading to in the `while (<F1>)` loop condition, which is short for `while ($_ = <F1>)`

In your programs you should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

And learn to use them, because they will save you lots of time when debugging, and give you vital information about what your program is doing.

So you get:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in,  "<",  "file1.txt" or die "Cannot open file1.txt for reading: $!";
open my $out, "+>", "file2.txt" or die "Cannot open file2.txt for overwrite: $!";

$/ = "\n\n";
while (<$in>) {
    if (/^: /) {
        print $out $_;
    }
}
```

Be advised that you can solve this with a simple one-liner program

```
perl -00 -nle 'print if /^: /' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks TLP,u have taken so much pain to explain many things here,as I am new to perl I was not knowing even basics,now I got very useful suggestions.I will try this out.But I have one question here,if entire record is a single record will this work  /^: / ?? i think it will rather check for ": " at the start of record.

Comment: Also, file2.txt need not to be exist before execution,as we used ">".thanks

Comment: entire paragraph is a single record.if this paragraph contains ": " at the start of line, i want to retain that entire paragraph.and all remaining paragraphs without this pattern (/^: /) to truncate from the file.

Comment: If you want to check for `: ` at the start of a line, you can use the `/m` modifier, which will allow the anchors `^` and `$` to also match at newlines, as well as start/end of string. I.e. `/^: /m`

Comment: this is really awesome..entire program can be replaced by a single line..great..perl is very strong..is this possible with awk?

Comment: Not sure, but I would expect it is.